# Speech to text conversion on a single click

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text

I am trying to implement the voice-to-text functionality on my flutter app by following the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDWoD1AaLu8. However, for the app to listen the next time, I have to press the button twice (to stop the previous session and then press again to start listening afresh). I want a single press of a button to convert speech to text.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:avatar_glow/avatar_glow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:highlight_text/highlight_text.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechScreenState createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  final Map<String, HighlightedWord> _highlights = {
    'flutter': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('flutter'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    'voice': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('voice'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    'subscribe': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('subscribe'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    'like': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('like'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    'comment': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('comment'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  };

  late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Press the button and start speaking';
  double _confidence = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Confidence: ${(_confidence * 100.0).toStringAsFixed(1)}%'),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
        animate: _isListening,
        glowColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        endRadius: 75.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        repeatPauseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        repeat: true,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _listen,
          child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 150.0),
          child: TextHighlight(
            text: _text,
            words: _highlights,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _listen() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) => setState(() {
            _text = val.recognizedWords;
            if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
              _confidence = val.confidence;
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the listening  if it has already been started, something like below

```
void _listen() async {

if (_isListening) {
  setState(() => _isListening = false);
  _speech.stop();
}

if (!_isListening) {
  bool available = await _speech.initialize(
    onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
    onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
  );
  if (available) {
    setState(() => _isListening = true);
    _speech.listen(
      onResult: (val) => setState(() {
        _text = val.recognizedWords;
        if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
          _confidence = val.confidence;
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
}
```

Comment: the listening stops forever

Comment: if '_speech.stop()' is a future, then put the initialisation part within _speech.stop().then( < initialisation part > )

Comment: you mean      _speech.stop().then(setState(() {
      _isListening = false;
    })); ?

Comment: I mean the listening stops after the first conversion. When I click after the first time, there is no listening (The listening and conversion is done only once)